# grpc Illegal wire type for field Message.Field .PeopleRequest.ages: 2 (0 expected))

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

Here is my proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package grpcClient;

service GrpcClient {
  rpc GetPeople(PeopleRequest) returns (PeopleResponse) {}
}
message PeopleRequest {
  repeated string names = 1; // ex: ['jack', 'marie']
  repeated int32 ages = 2; // ex: [18, 24]
}
message PeopleResponse {
  repeated Person people = 1;
}
message Person {
  string name = 1;
  int32 age = 2;
}
```

And here is the python stub construction:

```
from . import grpcClient_pb2
class GrpcClient:
    def __init__(self):
        server_url = "http://my_url:5001"
        secure_channel = make_secure_channel(server_url)
        self.__stub = grpcClient_pb2.GrpcClientStub(secure_channel)

    def get_people(self, **kwargs):
        people_request = grpcClient_pb2.PeopleRequest(**kwargs)
        # your test example
        try:
            serialized_people_request = grpcClient_pb2.PeopleRequest.SerializeToString(people_request)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            print('Serialized to binary of type {} and length {}'.format(type(serialized_people_request), len(serialized_people_request)))
        return self.__stub.GetPeople(people_request) # this throw an error
```

and here is my grpc call:

```
    grpcClient = GrpcClient()
grpcClient.get_people({ 'names': ['daniel', 'jack'] }) # this is OK
grpcClient.get_people({ 'names': ['daniel', 'jack'], 'ages': [18, 22] }) # this throws
```

I use **Python 3.6** and my pip packages versions are:

```
grpcio            1.0.4      
grpcio-tools      1.0.4
pip               9.0.1
protobuf          3.1.0.post1
```

I generate the `grpcClient_pb2.py` and the `grpcClient_pb2_grpc.py` using this command:

```
python -m grpc.tools.protoc -I./ --python_out=./ --grpc_python_out=./ ./grpcClient.proto
```

Note: And here is the auto-generated python code:

```
_descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='names', full_name='PeopleRequest.names', index=0,
      number=1, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=3,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=[],
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
_descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='ages', full_name='PeopleRequest.ages', index=1,
      number=2, type=5, cpp_type=1, label=3,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=[],
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
```

Many thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short story:** My server was written in node.js, and:

`rm -rf node_modules
npm i`

solved the problem for me.

**Long story:** It appears that whatever the server my client was connecting to (I had a local and a remote node.js server running for the test) in both case my client would throw. That's why I looked for an error in the client code, and not on the server side. Moreover, the server never logged anything, only the client throwed an error.

Finally I reimplemented the server side in python, and surprisingly my client wouldn't throw when connecting to the python server. So I started to suspect my node.js server had a problem, I finally completely reinstalled the **node_modules** of my node.js server, restarted, and indeed the problem disappeared. So I conclude the problem was related to some package in **node_modules**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is enough information to diagnose the issue. Could you please provide the entire proto file? I am assuming it contains a `GetPeoples` service.

Could you also provide your entire client program? With gRPC the imports can be confusing as you need to import things from *both* the `grpc` package and the generated `<your_proto>_pb2_grpc` package. It's not clear which of these `grpc.PeopleRequest` refers to.

I've tried to fill in the missing pieces with the following proto file which I named `test.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

service MyService {
  rpc GetPeoples(PeopleRequest) returns (PeopleReply) {}
}

message PeopleRequest {
  repeated string names = 1; // ex: ['jack', 'marie']
  repeated int32 ages = 2; // ex: [1, 2]
}

message PeopleReply {
}
```

And the following client, which works for me:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import grpc

import test_pb2
import test_pb2_grpc


def run():
  channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
  stub = test_pb2_grpc.MyServiceStub(channel)
  obj = test_pb2.PeopleRequest(
      names=['daniel'],
      ages=[32])
  print(obj)    # Ok, no error when building the object
  stub.GetPeoples(obj) # ERROR Illegal wire type for field ages: 2 (0 expected))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

This is what I did to build, [per the Python quickstart](http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html):

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ python --version
Python 2.7.6
(venv) $ pip install grpcio
(venv) $ pip install cython
(venv) $ pip install grpcio-tools
(venv) $ pip freeze
Cython==0.25.2
argparse==1.2.1
coverage==4.3.4
enum34==1.1.6
futures==3.0.5
grpcio==1.0.4
grpcio-tools==1.0.4
protobuf==3.1.0.post1
six==1.10.0
wheel==0.29.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
(venv) $ python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I. --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. test.proto
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hey many thanks for your test. I give more details on this ticket: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/9439 , your example is very similar to my code. Maybe it's the different python/grpc/protobuf versions...?  I'm away from keyboard right now, I'll do further investigation soon

Comment: could you tell which versions you are using (python/protobuf/grpcio), and how do you generate the test_pb2 and test_pb2_grpc? Thanks

Comment: just tried with python 3.5, throwing same error. I'm curious about your imports: ```import test_pb2, import test_pb2_grpc```, for me the ```test_pb2_grpc``` has a lot of duplicate imports at the top which causes problems, so I just skip it and use the Stub definition also available in the ````test_pb2````.

Comment: Interesting... I am on Python 2.7. I've modified my answer to include the build steps, including installation of `grpcio` and `grpcio-tools` from pypi. Doesn't look like I have Python 3.5 installed, but I will try to set it up and follow the same steps and report back. Can you try getting the [helloworld example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld) working first?

Comment: Works for me in Python 3.4 and Python 3.5.

Comment: Drove me crazy, finally found the problem. I just posted the solution for me. Many thanks for your time!